# If statement with random number generated in arraylist

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two questions concerning my code:

1. My ArrayList is now generating random numbers between 0 and 5. How can I make this between 1 and 5?
2. If one of the button is clicked, and if its number is for example 4 (*which isn't always the case, obviously*), I want something to happen; however, I have no idea how to write this in code. Thus, how would you go about doing that?

**EDIT**

More specific question 2, so I can try out some things

- How to get the current number that is generated on the button?

My implementation is;

```
package com.example.buttontester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GameOneActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gameone_layout);

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            numbers.add(i);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(numbers);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
        }

        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn1.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(0)));

        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn2.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(1)));

        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn3.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(2)));

        Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btn4.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(3)));

        Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn5.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(4)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

Comment: #2 be a bit more specific - what do you want to happen and what have you tried so far? If you have some code that shows what you've tried, post it in your question.

Comment: I haven't tried anything, because I don't know where to start and how to even get the current number that is generated @Darwind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

And you say:

> My ArrayList is now generating random numbers between 0 and 5, how can I make this between 1 and 5?

Well, then change the loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
```

Comment: When I did this, I got an java.lang.indexOutOdBoundsException, any ideas of what the cause is?

Comment: It only happens when `for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)` and not when `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, what can I do to get rid of this error? @MartijnCourteaux

Comment: Yes, change both loops.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change your loop to:

   for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
2. For the button you are interested in (e.g. 4), you need to set an onClickListener on the button. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Comment: I know I need to set an OnClickListener, but I want to know how to get the current number that is generated on a specific button @ian

Comment: well, you setText() on the button; all you have to do is button.getText() and check the value